# Understanding Streamline() Function

Tags: matlab, vector, streamline

I created a vector field using the quiver function `quiver(x,y,u,v)` where:

- x = column vector of x points
- y = column vector of y points
- u = column vector consisting of x component of vector at the corresponding (x,y)
- v = column vector consisting of y component of vector at the corresponding (x,y)

I get the following result:

[image: Result of Quiver function]

Now what I'd really like is a streamline, starting at one of the inner most points of the circle to see a path that leads to the outside of the circle. Thus I've been trying to use the streamline function as the following:

```
streamline(x,y,u,v,starting x, starting y)
```

Where `x,y,u,v` are all the same as used in the quiver function and `starting x` and `starting y` is just a `(x,y)` point.

The error I'm getting is

> Error using stream2 (line 47) U,V must all be size 2x2 or greater.

But I'm not sure why `u` and `v` must have at least 2 columns?

I haven't found much documentation or examples on using streamline like this so any insight as to what I'm doing wrong and what I should do fix it would really be appreciated!